# Combine attributes (lines) within an attribute table QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, combine

I have an attribute table with 100 LINES.
The table has a DATE field.
The 100 LINES have several DATE values. 
I would like to combine all LINES with the same DATE value.

How can i do that?

Comment: You could try using the **Dissolve** tool and select your `DATE` field :)